# Regular expression for the language $\{wtw^r \mid w, t \in\{0 \cup 1\}^+\}$

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

What is a regular expression for the language $C=\{wtw^r \mid w, t \in \{0 \cup 1\}^+\}$?
Here $w^r$ is the reverse of $w$.

Comment: See if the language can be represented by a much simpler expression, which might turn out to be regular.

Answer (score 1):

Let $wtw^R \in C$. This word can also be written as $xyx$ where $x \in \{0,1\}$ and $y \in \{0,1\}^+$ (pick $x$ as the first character of $w$, pick $y$ as $wtw^R$ except for the first and last characters).
Conversely, any word of the form $xyx$ with $x \in \{0,1\}$ and $y \in \{0,1\}^+$ belongs to $C$ (simply pick $w=w^R=x$ and $t=y$).

It follows that a regular expression for your language is
$(0(0|1)^+0) \mid (1(0|1)^+1)$ or, equivalently, $(0(0|1)(0|1)^*0) \mid (1(0|1)(0|1)^*1)$.